# Unable to Get Friend List Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, session

The following code i am using for Getting Friend List From Facebook, I have Session in Another class But Session data comming in this class properly . But after Request for getting Friend list from Facebook. i am getting graphObject {data:[] Just like this .. After that  getting JArry Null..

```
//Class For Getting FacebookUserdata 
private void getFacebookUserData() {
    Log.d(Utilities.logg, "getFacebookUserData");
    //Getting Session information
    Log.d(Utilities.logg, "session=" + session);
    Request requests;
    //Making request for getting Friend list
     requests = new Request(session, "me/friends", null, HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                 //On Complete Request
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    // threadForUI();

                    GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                    FacebookUserDataClass userData = null;
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                        //Exit from Dailog
                     if (json != null) {
                            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                mrootInnerInviteFriendsInitiateWars
                                        .setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
                                mrootInnerInitiateWars
                                        .setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                        //Array for getting data
                        JSONArray JArray = json.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < JArray.length(); i++) {
                            if (i == 10) {
                                mtvFriendLoadingInviteFriend
                                        .setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
                                setListAdapte(mChoose);
                            }
                              //Set Json Object for getting all friends 
                            JSONObject innerObject1 =  JArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    //.get(i);
                            //Geting Pojo Class
                            userData = new FacebookUserDataClass();

                            userData.setUserId((String) innerObject1
                                    .getString("id"));
                            userData.setUserName((String) innerObject1
                                    .getString("name"));
                            mFacebookUserDataListFull.add(userData);

                        }
                        placeFcaebookList();
                        mtvFriendLoadingInviteFriend
                                .setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
                        // if(Utilities.getSharedPref(Utilities.API_regId,
                        // "").isEmpty())
                        // {
                        // getSelfFacebookProfile();
                        // }
                        //Storing data into local database
                 Utilities.database
                                 .insertIntoFacebookFriendListTable(mFacebookUserDataListFull);
                        mckbCheckAll.setChecked(true);
                        checkUncheckAll(mChoose, true);
                        mbtnRefreshInviteFriend.setEnabled(true);
                        Utilities.foolFlag = false;
                        Utilities.saveFriendListOnServer(
                                mFacebookUserDataListFull,
                                Utilities.FACEBOOK);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.e(logg,
                                "getUserData EXCEPTION1 " + e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.e(logg,
                                "getUserData EXCEPTION2 " + e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        Utilities.errorFlag = true;
                        // onClickFacebookButton();
                    }

                }
            });

    pendingRequest = false;
    requests.executeAsync();

    // Utilities.database
    // .insertIntoFacebookFriendListTable(mFacebookUserDataListFull);
    // Utilities.foolFlag = false;
    // Utilities.saveFriendListOnServer(mFacebookUserDataListFull,
    // Utilities.FACEBOOK);
    // Log.d(logg, "frnds loding done");
    // getFacebookImages();
    //Getting Image from the Image Class
    new GetFacebookImagesUrl().execute();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any friends that are using the app? /me/friends returns all friends that are using the app not all friends you have. So it looks like it is working. And NO there is no way to get all friends

Comment: ohhh ok Then how i can get all friends ??

Comment: Did you read my comment. It ends with: And NO there is no way to get all friends

Comment: ok sorry but can you tell me that if above code is fine or not ??

Comment: No idea. I don't know Android at all. But if you get data:[] that looks correct

Comment: If you don't have other friends using the app, then `data: []` is the expected result.

Comment: I think i did mistake when asked that i want to get all friends.. Actually i want to get my facebook friend list. because i want to send request to user for game